# Passing props to child using Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There's a lot of questions and answers around what I'm asking, but I feel like I'm reading it and applying it correctly it just isn't working and I'm getting undefined on my `props` every time.

So I have my parent component here:

let meeting = {
  title: 'Some title',
};

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render((
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Start} dataMeeting={meeting} />
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        <Modal />
      </div>
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

Then in my other file where my `Start` component is I do a `console.log` on `this.props`

```
export default class Start extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.dataMeeting);
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my `console.log` I get back undefined, and when I just `console.log` the `this.props` I can't see my `dataMeeting` in the object.

Any idea why I'm misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using `react-router` v4, you can pass props by using the `render` prop instead of `component`:

```
<Route path="/" render={()=><Start dataMeeting={meeting} />}/>
```

As @ToddChaffe pointed out, you could (but should not) use the `component` prop in the same manner:

```
<Route path="/" component={()=><Start dataMeeting={meeting} />}/>
```

however that will recreate the component on every render.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Been smashing my head around reading for hours and not understand why it isn't working. Makes sense now :) Thanks again!

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help! `react-router` documentation has been a moving target lately! :-)

Comment: You might want to add that you can also use component `<Route path="/" component={()=><Start dataMeeting={meeting} />}/>`. And that if you do so, it has the disadvantage of re-creating the component on every render, which is the main reason for using `render`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very poorly documented, but you should use `this.props.route`.

```
export default class Start extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.route.dataMeeting);
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```